# A lot of Foreign keys on a system to record "Likes" and comments

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, query-performance, sqlperformance

I create simple post like comment system. People can "like" posts and leave comments. They can also "like" other peoples' comments. 
I have a table like this:

```
----Columns---
--like_id ---
-- post_id(which post user liked)---
-- user_id--
-- comment_id(which comment user liked)
```

But I should use foreign keys and indexes for ALL. I think this will be really heavy to create 4 indexes and foreign keys.Or should I use another table for comment likes?

Comment: (1) I removed extraneous database tags.  (2) Indexes are there to enhance performance, so having multiple indexes is not *per se* a problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but I heard that INDEXES slow down insert query performance which is really important case in like system

Comment: . . Indexes need to be updated during inserts, which slows down inserts.  What is your insert volume?  If you have a high volume, then perhaps you don't want to be running complex queries on the same system.

Comment: You `INSERT` a row once.  You `UPDATE` that row's "like counter" many times.  The one insert must deal with indexes.  The many updates love having the relevant index already in place.  Think about it.

Comment: So... @RickJames what you suggest in this case?Should not  I use any Index?Or how I should do with indexes in this example?

Comment: You have a table of comments, correct?  It has a `PRIMARY KEY`, correct?  When someone "likes" that comment, what info do you have?  Perhaps that `KEY`?  If so, you have what you need.

Comment: Yes but I cant decide should I use foreign key for all of them?because foreign key is really helpfull when someone try hack for example someone  try to like to  post which doesnt exist  and foreign key will remove it and in this case it will be really helpful and fast but if I insert new row it will be probably slow than normal.

Answer (score 0):

RDMS systems are made for this. They handle indexes efficiently. Don't worry about performance here until your tables have at least a million rows each.

When that starts to happen you'll have plenty of time and money to optimize your database systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,Is it good to sepererate posts_likes and comments_likes to two different table?